# Dart Angular2 in WebStorm: "Attribute [(ngModel)] is not allowed her ..."

Tags: angular, dart, webstorm, angular-dart

G'Day,

Trying to follow the Angular2 'Heros Editor' tutorial using Dart in WebStorm:

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';

@Component( selector: 'my-app',
    styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
    template: '<input [(ngModel)]="hero" placeholder="name">')

class AppComponent{ String hero = "Seth Ladd"; }
```

The WebStorm IntelliSense marks [(ngModel)] as "Attribute [(ngModel)] is not allowed here...".

Am I missing an import or a setting to have WebStorm recognize Angular2 in Dart?

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebStorm doesn't support AngularDart at the moment an you may get some false warnings in injected HTML. Also you may miss Angular specific code completion, highlighting, code navigation, etc.
Watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11590.

Comment: Are you sure? Since WebStorm even has project templates for Angular2 with Dart. And it works just fine for me :)

Comment: The project templates come from [stagehand](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehand) which is integrated into WebStorm/IntelliJ and Alexander is a JetBrains employee and knows what he's talking about.

Comment: Ah, mea culpa! Still wondering what does the magic for me then :S